# Acumatica: Cannot call DAC Extension class on BLC

Tags: acumatica

I customized the Entry Type form and added some new fields, as I added a new method i cannot call the DLC extension.

[image: Unable to locate DAC Extension]

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, since the Acumatica 5.1 it inserts the code on App_RuntimeCode instead App_Cache folder in which makes the DAC class extension or the BLC undetected causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
protected void
```

with

```
protected virtual void
```

Comment: Could you present your face and graph extension code?

Answer (score 0):

- Did you rebuilt your project after adding DAC Extension?
- Is both DAC Extension and BLC Extension under same Namespace, If not
  did you import the namespace of DAC Extension in to your BLC
  Extension?
- Is both DAC and BLC extension in same project, if not did you add the
  reference to your DAC Extension project and import the namespace in
  your BLC extension project?

Comment: 1. Yes, I do it everytime i make changes.
2. Yes, it's on the same namespace.
3. Yes, it's on the same project.

Comment: I tried your code in my system and i didnt get any issues you mentioned.
http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1mmOzq4aP4GqX8TzuE6slKA5vkMKWY1

You may try cleaning your project assemblies and the temporary asp path [Close visual studio before doing this] then rebuild the project and see. If still have isssues, please give your code for DAC here.

Comment: yes i still do, i guess it wasn't in my DAC class, since it was generated by acumatica when I added those fields. well as of now what i do is, i do it through Acumatica 4.2. and events are done through 5.1.

Comment: I usually follow creating a DAC in the extension project and adding database table column in the package.

Comment: I found out the cause why it wont recognize the DAC class, it routes through App_Code folder and not in App_Runtime which is weird because when I open the customization project all codes created are in the App_RuntimeCode folder

Comment: Yes, when you use ACE it creates the file in App_Code >  caches when you publish your project. You can actually write that extension directly in your project (AEF) instead of using customization engine (ACE).